# Running Magento Using Vagrant / Puphpet

Tags: php, magento, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I'm trying to setup a development environment for Magento using Virtualbox and Puphpet.  I've tried both Apache and Nginx configurations.  The result is:  Magento installs just fine and pages load, however, none of my products show up on the front-end.  They show up fine on the admin panel.  I'm also unable to upload product images on the admin side and receive this error:

```
Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.
```

However, if I issue `vagrant halt` and use a plain old MAMP setup, the site loads just fine..

So I'm assuming it's something in the vagrant config, or perhaps a permissions issue.  However, the permissions are obviously the same in my vagrant as on my local machine (where i successfully ran the MAMP version using the same files). I have very open permissions on on my `media` folder.

I don't get any Apache, console, or PHP errors.  Everything else on the Magento site loads fine (other pages, or images).  Just product related items (categories, products, product images) will not load.

Attached is my Puphpet config file.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/centos65-x64
        box_url: puphpet/centos65-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '512'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.102
            forwarded_port:
                53TCVuCd1ZcH:
                    host: '8251'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            gPMblwTujftQ:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim-common
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: "Off"
    modules:
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        ZkhsTRJZGFky:
            servername: studioconcierge.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.studioconcierge.dev
            docroot: /var/www
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    vhosts:
        M8ymcW4nyI2e:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '55'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Los_Angeles
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: '9000'
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        iJ4ng1dlb6yo:
            version: ''
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions:
        KwuFzvIv8udn:
            version: ''
mysql:
    install: '1'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: vagrant
    adminer: '1'
    databases:
        tOOhhSMmWoji:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: studioconcierge
            host: localhost
            user: studioAdmin
            password: 1studio!
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        java_install: true
        autoupgrade: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

In my case, PHP GD was not installed in the Vagrant config.  So in the PHP section of my Puphpet config, i added:

```
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '55'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - gd
    pear: {  }
    pecl:
        - pecl_http
ini:
    display_errors: On
    error_reporting: '-1'
    session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
timezone: America/Los_Angeles
mod_php: 0
```